# Cannot cannot convert Generic string in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to declare a list of strings and added DateTime to it. However I get the error `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'` when I do something like this as given below:

```
    public List<string> AllTime_ = new List<string>();

    void Start () {
        AllTime_.Add(Data.Select (d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString ("HH")).ToList ());

        AllTime_.Add(Data.Select (d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString ("mm")).ToList ());
    }
```

But when I do the same by declaring the List such as given below, it throws no errors and works well. Only problem is the List is redefined and the size of the list changes. How do I try and fix my first way of the problem by adding to the list?

```
    public List<string> AllTime_ = new List<string>();

    void Start () {
        AllTime_ = new List<string> (Data.Select (d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString ("HH")).ToList ());

        AllTime_ = new List<string> (Data.Select (d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString ("mm")).ToList ());
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AllTime_` is a `List<string>` so each element is **one single `string`** not again a `List<string>` so `Add` has a single `string` as parameter - you are trying to give it an entire list.

> Only problem is the List is redefined and the size of the list changes

This doesn't sound quite right either ;) What happens is you overwrite the list. The size should be the same since you `Select` the same amount of items. What you rather want though is combining both results into one single list.

You are probably looking for [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange)

```
AllTime_.Clear();
AllTime_.AddRange(Data.Select (d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString ("HH")));
AllTime_.AddRange(Data.Select (d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString ("mm")));
```

---

Though I wonder why adding the same times twice but as separate formattings? Wouldn't it make more sense to always have pairs of the "lines" belonging together? Also this does the parse work twice.

I would probably rather do e.g.

```
AllTime_.Clear();
foreach(var d in Data.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact (d, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{
    AllTime_.Add(date.ToString("HH"));
    AllTime_.Add(date.ToString("mm"));
}
```

Comment: Oh just for this questions :) I am adding HH and MM in two lines there.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather want to combine these like e.g. `ToString("HH\nmm")` ? or something similar? currently you are first adding all HH "lines" and then after these all mm ones .. looks a bit odd and does the work of parsing twice ;)

Answer (score 4):

`Data.Select(...)`, in this case, returns `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>`.

The `Add` method of a `List<string>`, expects a string as a parameter. Since you are giving a list, it is giving you the exception you are seeing.

If you want to add all the strings inside that list, to `AllTime`, you could do:

```
AllTime_.AddRange(Data.Select(d => ....))
```